# Shell script to Find ,Remove and print files removed

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I'm creating a script to maintain database backup directories that should retain files only seven days.

This is what i have created

```
set +vx
BACKUP_DIR=/mounts/prd
myarray=(`cat /u01/postgres_prod_server.txt`)

for SERVER in "${myarray[@]}"
do
   echo "   SERVER: $SERVER"
   if [ -d $BACKUP_DIR/$SERVER ]; then
      find $BACKUP_DIR/$SERVER/5431/ -type f -name '*.tar' -mtime +7 -exec rm -rf {} \; | tee /tmp/log.txt | wc -l | xargs echo "Files deleted:" >> /tmp/log.txt;
      find $BACKUP_DIR/$SERVER/5432/ -type f -name '*.tar' -mtime +7 -exec rm -rf {} \; | tee /tmp/log1.txt | wc -l | xargs echo "Files deleted:" >> /tmp/log1.txt;
   fi

done
```

Here is what i'm looking to do but its not working.

1.i'm unable to print what the find command is deleting and send to log file.

Comment: What is the expected output for your log? just piping stuff will of course not work

Comment: Might not be the solution you're looking for but a `glob` can be used for the directory name `543[12]` . Then you only need one `find` invocation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`-exec` won't print anything, but you can use `-print` option to do that. See https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/503530/527050.

Also, `...| tee /tmp/log.txt` will truncate the log file, so you need to add option `-a` to keep previous log.

Final script looks like this: (The path of a log file is used twice, so you may want to store it in a variable.)

```bash
LOG_FILE=/tmp/log.txt
SEARCH_DIR="$BACKUP_DIR/$SERVER/5431/"

find "${SEARCH_DIR}" -type f -name '*.tar' -mtime +7 \
  -exec rm -rf {} \; -print | \
  tee -a "${LOG_FILE}" | \
  wc -l | \
  xargs echo "Files deleted:" >> "${LOG_FILE}";
```